# How do you get the following char in (.each_char)?

Tags: ruby

Current code:

```
myString.length.times do |i|  
    if myString[i] >= myString[i+1]
      DOES SOMETHING
    end
end
```

I would like to change the code above to something like this:

```
myString.each_char do |char|

   if char >= nextChar
     DOES SOMETHING  
   end
end
```

How would you get that **nextChar** (like i+1)?

Comment: Thank you, Cary Swoveland, that is very not helpful. The code above is not intended to be run through IRB, nor is it the code that I am working on. It's purpose is to illustrate the question. Thanks for posting this response without reading it.

Comment: Your code does not show what you want to do. What is meant, for example, by `([myString[i+1]-[myString[i])`? What is the difference between two characters? The class `String` has no method `-`.  Readers will be puzzled by that. Even your minor errors (e.g., omitting `end` for the method definition) and improper indentation will put readers off.  Why should they spend time helping you if you don't respect them by eliminating obvious errors before posting your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like `my_string.each_char.each_cons(2) do |char, next_char|`. [each_cons is](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) shorthand for "each_consecutive".

Answer (score 0):

Here is your current code (as I understand it), corrected:

```
my_string = "cat on a hot tin roof"

new_string = ''
(my_string.length-1).times do |i|
  if my_string[i] >= my_string[i+1]
    new_string << my_string[i]
  else
    new_string << my_string[i+1]
  end
end
new_string
  #=> "cttoonaahottttnnrroo"
```

I could not decipher `([myString[i+1]-[myString[i])`. Not only does it have two unbalanced open braces, but the String class has no method `-`.  You can see above what I have assumed.

Here is one way to change this code to the design you want:

```
enum = my_string.chars.to_enum
new_string = ''
loop do
  c   = enum.next
  nxt = enum.peek
  new_string << ((c >= nxt) ? c : nxt)
end
new_string
  #=> "cttoonaahottttnnrroo"
```

Here is what is happening. First we convert the characters of `my_string` to an enumerator, using the method [Object#to_enum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-to_enum).

```
enum = my_string.chars.to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["c", "a", "t", " ", "o", "n", " ", "a", " ", "h", "o",
  #                  "t", " ", "t", "i", "n", " ", "r", "o", "o", "f"]:each>
```

Next we create an empty string, `new_string`, and then step through each element of `enum`, using [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html).  [Enumerator#next](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) returns the next element of `enum` and [Enumerator#peek](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) returns the following element.  `next` and `peek` differ in that the former advances the current value of the enumerator while the latter does not.

If the enumerator is at it's last value, executing `next` or `peek` will raise a `StopIteration` exception. `loop` handles this exception by breaking from the loop (which is why I've used `loop`, rather than `while...`, etc.) It is evident that it will be `peek` that raises the `StopIteration` exception.